# Android 2 activities and pass datas

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onstart

I have a problem with my app android. I new in this, and i'm learning. I have 2 activities, first call the second activity and in this activity i add string, and i want see this new string in the first activity, I try with this code

```
protected void onStart() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    paises.add(bundle.getString("Pais"));
    Log.i("pais", bundle.getString("Pais"));
    habitantes.add(bundle.getString("Habitantes"));

    super.onStart();
}
```

I try with OnCreate, OnResume and my app close, anyone can help me?

In the second activity I put this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Pais", pa);
i.putExtra("Habitantes", ha);
```

EDIT: Is a simple app, in the first activity i have a arrayList, and i want in another activity add to this arrayLista a string, but when i turn to the first activity the arraylist don't update :S

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("Pais", pa);
args.putString("Habitantes", ha);
i.putExtras(args);
```

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method putExtra(String, String) is undefined for the type Bundle anyadirPais.java

Comment: Sorry, meant putString();

Comment: I try to put this and Alex says and nothing :-(

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `super.onStart()` first thing.

```
void onStart(Bundle savedState) {
   super.onStart(savedState);
   // your code here .....
}
```

same for `onResume` and `onCreate`

Comment: With OnResume my app crash, and with onresume never enter... what is the method that i can put??

Comment: onCreate. First call super.onCreate then put in your stuff

Comment: I cant put in OnCreate because, is the second activity who call the first with a new data.

Answer (score 0):

It works, ty Alex and Bene, the right form is a mix with you ^^

The first activity onCreate

```
 if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        paises.add(bundle.getString("Pais"));
        habitantes.add(bundle.getString("Habitantes"));
    }
```

The second activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("Pais", pa);
args.putString("Habitantes", ha);
i.putExtras(args);
startActivity(i)
```